# Flutter - Dictionary Object to JSON Object

Tags: swift, flutter, plugins

I develop a flutter plugin in which i call my native SDK and after processing receive response in flutter class from Native iOS SDK.
IOS SDK return response in NSDictionary in which some quotation " "  is missing and some keys also null show as it is.

```
["declined_codes": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x281071a50>(

MB1964

)

, "services_declined_codes": {

document = (

MB1964

);

}, "verification_data": {

document = {

dob = "<null>";

"document_number" = "<null>";

"expiry_date" = "<null>";

gender = "<null>";

"issue_date" = "<null>";

name = {

"first_name" = "<null>";

"last_name" = "<null>";

"middle_name" = "<null>";

};

"selected_type" = (

""

);

"supported_types" = (

passport,

"id_card",

"driving_license",

"credit_or_debit_card"

);
};

}, "email": <null>, "verification_result": {

document = {

dob = "<null>";

document = 0;

"document_country" = "<null>";

"document_must_not_be_expired" = "<null>";

"document_number" = "<null>";

"document_proof" = "<null>";

"document_visibility" = "<null>";

"expiry_date" = "<null>";

gender = "<null>";

"issue_date" = "<null>";

name = "<null>";

"selected_type" = "<null>";

};

}, "country": US, "declined_reason": The document is not visible., "event": declined, "reference": package_sample_Flutter, "info": {

agent = {

"browser_name" = "";

"device_name" = 0;

"is_desktop" = 1;

"is_phone" = 0;

"platform_name" = "";

useragent = "";

};
geolocation = {

asn = 111111;

capital = US;

city = US;

"continent_code" = AS;

"continent_name" = US;

"country_code" = US;

"country_name" = US;

currency = USD;

host = "";

ip = "";

"ip_type" = ;

isp = "";

latitude = "";

longitude = "";

"metro_code" = "";

"postal_code" = 1111;

rdns = "";

"region_code" = IS;

"region_name" = us;

timezone = "us";

};

}]
```

I use below method to get values from response but not get any response can you please suggest something to fix this issue.

print(jsonDecode(staticResponse)["reference"]);

I try below method in dart file but response not get.
print(jsonDecode(staticResponse)["reference"]);